# Ada list running process in Linux

Tags: linux, ada

I am trying to write a program to control the processes that are running on the Linux system. I am interested in knowing the memory and CPU consumption of the processes and start, kill and pause the processes on the system.

The nearest library I can think of is GNAT.Os_Lib package, how can I do such a monitoring in Ada?

Any direction in this regard would help

Answer (score 4):

I think on linux you need to look at the contents of the /proc directory.
Nothing specific to Ada here, using GNAT.Directory_Operations or Ada.Directories should work to read the contents of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

`POSIX.Signals.Send_Signal` is probably the right procedure to call, when you want to kill or pause processes.

I'm not aware of published Ada libraries for monitoring running processes and their resource usage.  I would look into the implementation of `ps` for Linux, and import the relevant C functions into an Ada package.

Comment: Jacob, would'nt Florist do the trick, at least for CPU consumption, with POSIX.Process_Times and ? Sorry if I'm wrong, I never used this but it was the first thin I thought about when speaking about processes.

Comment: That only works internally in the process.  I read the question as being about interrogating the operating system about **other** processes.